# Where can I find good literature for beginners?

Tags: learning

I am trying to find some database tutorials,books and similar, since I have started this course in college, and received some material, but it is really hard to manage through all the info on the net. I searched through the questions on the site but didn't find any. Thankfull for all your input.

Comment: This existing question may answer some of your questions: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/445/247

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are looking for something on an overview level rather than a practical level.  If you are interested in learning about Oracle databases from a practical level, there is no better place to start than the [Oracle Concepts Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

As Dynamo already commented, it might be better if you specify which aspect of "databases" you are interested in.

If it happens to be database design, I can strongly recommend **"Beginning Database Design"** by *Clare Churcher*. It's a very accessible book, but points you into the correct direction ("normalization").

A source more valuable than this website here should be the lecturer of the course you are taking (or the teaching assistant if there are exercises). Did you ask her/him? (If you don't trust the lecturer for this question, you should consider dropping the course.)

Answer (score 2):

Clear and concise introduction to the SQL language: [The Language of SQL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/143545751X)

Answer (score 2):

Not for basic concepts but for technical references, I always prefer the sites from the DBMS itself. They are all really good IMO and most of them have a "Getting Started" or "Beginner" section.

- [MySQL DevZone](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index.html)
- [PostgreSQL Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/index.html)
- [Oracle Docs](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db111/portal.portal_db?selected=1&frame=#new_to_oracle_database_11g)
- [MS SQL @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187875.aspx)

Be sure to check out the comments (if available). Sometimes, a real gem is hidden there.

Answer (score -1):

[PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) is a good choice because is really open source!

The project have a great [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/manuals/), really simple and understandable.
Also, the community is very reliable and dedicated providing a great maturity to
the project.

A good and a complete option to start in database world.

If you are a kind of person that like books, I could suggest:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/books/