# How long to learn PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, learning

I want to learn PostgreSQL and How to make the learning process efficient, but really don't know how long it would take even after googling my question.

I used MySQL before and knew relational database. However, I would like to use PostgreSQL the implement my web back end database management system. I want sufficient knowledge to do it, design not ugly structure, write not ugly code, like I used MySQL for another web app project before.

I am not asking the specific time, but at least I want a sketch in my mind. How much effort I need to invest? What kind of problem I would have? Any lessons you learned can be shared?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

As developer, not a full-time DBA, I use Postgres for some of my work. But it is not my focus. I found Postgres very confusing and frustrating when getting started. After a long career using [4D](http://www.4D.com/), I was an pro in relational database design and normalization, but a newbie with SQL and "black-box" database engines. Below is a list of the resources that helped me.

I look at Postgres not as a product to be mastered such as a new IDE or email client app. I see it more as a computer system unto itself, to be explored bit by bit. Some areas I may never touch ([PostGIS](http://postgis.net), geo data), while others are vital to me ([UUID data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html), [XML data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-xml.html), [date-time data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html)).

➥ So I see "learning Postgres" not as a goal to be accomplished but as an on-going process.

The more I learn about Postgres, the more impressed and awed I become. It took some investment of time and effort, but now I ♥ 🐘 (the [Blue Elephant](https://www.postgresql.org/about/press/presskit10/#graphics)).

## Tips

### Smart Defaults

When in doubt, go with Postgres’ defaults.

### UTF-8

One exception to the 'smart defaults' tip: Almost always best to specify [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) as the character encoding. Do so when installing Postgres, as this defines the default when you later create databases. When you do create databases, verify that `UTF-8` is the encoding is in use.

### Security

Postgres is designed for security as a priority. By default you can only connect from a process/app running locally on the same machine. You must change the security configuration to connect from across a local network or internet.

### Installers

To get started you must install Postgres. The main 3 ways to do that:

- Compile from source.
- Download easy-to-use installers built and provided by the [EnterpriseDB](http://www.enterprisedb.com/) as a courtesy to the community. They provide installers for their [commercial enhanced version of Postgres](http://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads?quicktabs_postgres_plus_dwnlds=0#quicktabs-postgres_plus_dwnlds) as well as [plain-vanilla free-of-cost Postgres](http://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads?quicktabs_postgres_plus_dwnlds=1#quicktabs-postgres_plus_dwnlds) for Mac OS X, Linux, and Windows.
- For Mac OS X users, [Postgres.app](http://postgres.app/) is an alternative, a double-clickable Mac app.

On some hosted servers such as Heroku or Amazon, the host may offer to spin up Postgres on your behalf. So no installation required in that case.

Regarding uninstalling:

- [*Uninstall Postgres 10 on macOS – EnterpriseDB installer*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/185476/19079)

### Client-Server

Postgres is a black-box, hiding your data inside. To access, you must use a utility tool to make a connection to the Postgres daemon process. For getting started, use either of these tools usually included with your Postgres installation.

- [pgAdmin](http://pgadmin.org) for GUI app access
- [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) for command-line access

### Virtual Machines

When playing around or experimenting with Postgres, I suggest using a virtual machine so you can later throw it away. Postgres is a pretty heavy installation, creating a new Unix-level user. Entirely removing Postgres can be a bit tricky.

#### Local

I use [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) 9, 10, and 11 for virtual machines running [Mac OS X Mountain Lion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) or [El Capitan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) to install various versions of Postgres 9.*. On a Mac, besides Parallels, you might be able to use [VMware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/) or [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org).

#### Cloud

Another route is a cloud server. Renting by the hour can be quite inexpensive, perhaps in the range of a penny (USD $0.01) or nickel or dime an hour. You should be able to delete your virtual machine when done or when you want to start from scratch with a fresh one. Examples include [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com), [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), and [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com).

## In-Person Resources

### PUGs

Find a PUG. Not a [dog](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pug), a Postgres User Group. Search [MeetUp.com](http://www.meetup.com) and search [this list](http://www.postgresql.org/community/user-groups/).

Attend every meeting. Let discussions wash over you even when you cannot understand it all. Postgres has *many* features, add-ons, related products. Postgres has much depth. So don't expect to master Postgres, just keep looking for ways to use it.

If you cannot find one near you, start one.

### Experts

Learn the names of some of the Postgres experts who are generous about sharing their knowledge. Pay special attention when they speak. For example, [Craig Ringer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/7788/craig-ringer) on [this page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/83430/19079). Other examples, [Josh Berkus](https://plus.google.com/116763716624645578717), [Bruce Momjian](https://plus.google.com/111546890870181560515), [David E. Wheeler](http://justatheory.com/), [Selena Deckelmann](http://www.chesnok.com/daily/).

### Events

#### pgDay

You can find one-day "pgDay" events as well as multi-day Postgres conferences all over the world. For example, [France](https://twitter.com/PGDAY_Fr), [Prague](http://www.p2d2.cz/), [India](http://pgday.in/), [Finland](http://2016.nordicpgday.org/), and [Singapore](http://2016.pgday.asia/). See [this list](http://www.postgresql.org/about/eventarchive/).

#### Multi-Day Conferences

In North America the multi-day conferences include:

- [PGCon](https://www.pgcon.org/) in Ottawa.
- [pgOpen](https://postgresopen.org/) in Chicago.

#### Other Events

You can often find a Postgres booth at other geek events as well.

For example, visit me while volunteering at the [SeaPUG](http://seapug.org/) booth next April at [LinuxFest Northwest 2016](http://linuxfestnorthwest.org/2016) in [Bellingham WA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellingham,_Washington), USA (outside Seattle). Postgres consulting companies have had booths in the past.

## Online Resources

### Postgres Weekly

Read [Postgres Weekly](http://postgresweekly.com/), a collection of select Postgres-related articles and news. Curated by an expert, [Craig Kerstiens](https://twitter.com/craigkerstiens). Published weekly, thus the name.

### Mailing Lists

Subscribe to the [Postgres mailing lists](http://www.postgresql.org/list/).

I find it enlightening to skim through the weekly *PostgreSQL Weekly News* email delineating that week's work including a list of patches submitted. Posted on the [Announce list](http://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-announce/). All the nitty-gritty details are beyond my comprehension, but nevertheless I become more and more familiar. I learn a bit about the many different features inh Postgres. And I learn how seriously the team takes their work, with an emphasis on solid quality.

### Planet Postgres, blog portal

[Planet Postgres](http://planet.postgresql.org) is a consolidator of Postgres-related blogs.

Answer (score 6):

It shouldn't take long to get up to speed to a reasonable degree if you've used another RDBMS. Read some guidance on PostgreSQL for MySQL users to help you adapt to sequences vs `auto_increment`, ANSI-standard quoting (though you should be using that in MySQL already), the stricter data type checking, how authentication and roles work, `psql`'s backslash commands instead of MySQL's `SHOW TABLES`, etc.

There are [plenty](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Things_to_find_out_about_when_moving_from_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL) of [resources](http://granjow.net/postgresql.html) out there. Google has many, many more.

If you run MySQL in ANSI STRICT mode, you're going to have less trouble moving to PostgreSQL.

More learning is required if you're setting up replication and failover, and for managing backups etc, as they're significantly more different than the SQL-level interface is.