# Uninstall Postgres 10 on macOS – EnterpriseDB installer

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x, postgresql-10

Title says it all… How to completely remove a Postgres cluster from a macOS computer?

I used the [installer app provided](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads#macosx) by [EnterpriseDB](https://www.enterprisedb.com) as a courtesy to the community.

This uninstallation question has been asked multiple times on Stack Overflow. But those questions and answers are years out-of-date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## `postgres` user

The user account named `postgres` (by default) created by the installer is actually a macOS user account.

- Apple allows deleting a user account in the more recent versions of macOS: `System Preferences` > `Users & Groups` > `-` button in list, after authenticating with padlock icon in lower corner.
- In older macOS versions that do not delete user accounts, you may be able to [hide that user account](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203998).

Every other trace of Postgres can be removed.

## Backup/Export

Of course, first [backup your database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html) with a tool like pgBackup. And/or export your data.

## `Uninstaller` app

The installer app provided by EnterpriseDB does install an app named `Uninstaller`. Find it in the Postgres folder, probably located at the root `Library` folder (not the `Library` folder in your home folder).

> /Library/PostgreSQL/10

Run that uninstaller app, and supply your macOS system password. After the run, the data folder remains as that is owned by the `postgres` user rather than your regular macOS user. The uninstaller app reminds you of this fact.

> /Library/PostgreSQL/10/data

[image: screen shot of the Finder with Postgres data folder selected]

### `data` folder

Select that `data` folder in the Finder, and choose `File` > `Move to trash`. When prompted, provide your own macOS user account password.

Delete that outer Postgres folder(s) that contained `data`.

### `Applications` folder

Remove the `PostgreSQL 10` folder in your `Applications` folder if it remains. Again, provide your own macOS user account password.

[image: screen shot of the Finder showing "PostgreSQL 10" folder in Applications folder]

Comment: If it helps anyone, I found the `uninstall.app` in `/Users/vignesh/PostgreSQL/uninstall` folder.

Answer (score 3):

As an addendum to [the current accepted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/185477/116653):

To remove the `Postgres` user:

- Go to System Preferences -> Users & Groups
- Click the lock icon on the bottom left corner and enter your password
- Select the `Postgres` user and click the minus button, confirm in the dialog

Tested on Siera 10.12