# Removing postgres connection installed with EnterpriseDB on MacOS

Tags: postgresql, installation

I had earlier installed Postgres using Enterprise DB which is installed by default at location: /Library/PostgreSQL/10

However, because of some database issues I had to uninstall it. I followed all the steps given [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185476/uninstall-postgres-10-on-macos-enterprisedb-installer/185477#185477).

Today i tried to reinstall the postgres using homebrew. Installation was successful but when I run the below command to start the service it give the following message.

```
MacBook-Pro ~ % pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start

waiting for server to start....2020-05-21 14:15:45.793 CEST [6798] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 
12.3 on x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0, compiled by Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang- 
1103.0.32.59), 64-bit
2020-05-21 14:15:45.794 CEST [6798] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2020-05-21 14:15:45.794 CEST [6798] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-05-21 14:15:45.795 CEST [6798] LOG:  could not bind Unix address 
"/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432":Address already in use
2020-05-21 14:15:45.795 CEST [6798] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 
5432? If not, remove socket file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" and retry.
2020-05-21 14:15:45.795 CEST [6798] WARNING:  could not create Unix-domain socket in 
directory "/tmp"
2020-05-21 14:15:45.795 CEST [6798] FATAL:  could not create any Unix-domain sockets
2020-05-21 14:15:45.796 CEST [6798] LOG:  database system is shut down
stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

I guess it is suggesting that the port 5432 is in use by another instance of postgres so i am trying to find and stop the process but it does not list any PID:

```
MacBook-Pro ~ % lsof -i :5432
MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Not sure what I should do next to completely stop the postgres installed via Enterprise DB and start the one installed with homebrew. Kindly guide me with this.

Comment: You need to run `lsof` with elevated privileges, for instance with `sudo lsof`

Comment: Yes, I did but that does not change outcome

Comment: Then remove `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` as suggested in the log output.

Comment: How to remove? Where is it located ? It does not return any location when I try to locate it with sudo locate PGSQL.5432

Comment: sudo rm /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432